# Marklogic index creation on xml value

Tags: marklogic

XML structure looks something like this:

```
   <division>
     <sub-divison>
       <name>
         mime-type
       </name>
       <value>
         .jpeg
       </value>
     </sub-divison>
     <sub-divison>
        <name>
          status
        </name>
        <value>
          Work In Progress
        </value>
     </sub-divison>
    </division>
```

I need to index **mime-type** and **status**. What sort of indexing mechanism should be used, `Path-Range-index` or someother? Somehow I feel its not the right. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to do anything. MarkLogic automatically indexes element values, element-attribute values, and words. So without any configuration changes, you can write XPath expressions and construct cts:query terms for `name` and `value`. Those will use the built-in element value indexes. Try that, and see if it is fast enough for your application. If it isn't, the problem might be in the query rather than the indexing. You can use http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan or http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:query-trace to see which indexes are used.

However there is some room for improvement. In your XML the `value` element does not mean much of anything until the `name` element is also examined. By analogy, consider what SQL would do when you have a column `name` and a column `value`, and want to select `WHERE name=? AND value=?`. The SQL evaluator would have to look up by `name`, and look up by `value`, and join the results. MarkLogic will do something similar, joining two lookup terms. At large scale, joins are expensive.

So if you want optimal performance, refactor your XML to look more like this:

```
<division>
 <sub-divison>
   <mime-type>.jpeg</mime-type>
   <status>.jpeg</status>
 </sub-divison>
</division>
```

With XML like that, a query on a single element no longer requires any joins. A query using both `status` and `mime-type` will join the results of those two lookups, while the old XML would have to join from three lookups. As a side benefit, that XML is also easier for a human to read and understand.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.Initially the xml format was in the way you suggested but now the requirement is changed and i would be getting xml in the format that i have mentioned.I had element range indexes on mime-type and status for the kind of xml you suggested but with the new format will element range index is any use?

Comment: I'd guess not, but it depends on what you're doing with those elements.

Comment: all operations except search I am able to do with the new xml format I have posted. I need to search against fields like mime-type or status. With old xml format I used to use search:search api along with grammar, word and value constraint. How do I do this with current xml format. Is it not possible to add constraints as xpath expressions. Also I need to facet and highlights.

Comment: I think your question about indexing XML values has been answered. But you could post a new question about how best to use the search:search API with your XML.